# Toggle toolbar in ipython notebook (keyboard shortcut)

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have not been able to find anything online about this. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You can toggle it from the *View* menu, but I don't think there's a keyboard shortcut. You can [add custom keyboard shortcuts](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending/frontend_extensions.html#modifying-key-bindings).

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I'm asking this question because I've added this line to my .jupyter/custom/custom.css file: `div#maintoolbar, div#header {display: none !important;}`, which removes the toolbar entirely.

Comment: Aha. I don't know if our toggle would override that. I guess you've found out?

Comment: That css code also removes all the File, Edit, View, ... menu items haha

Comment: Ah. That might be a bit too aggressive ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Keyboard Shortcut in iPython (Jupyter) Notebook by choosing the **Help** option on Menu bar and then clicking on **Edit Keyboard Shortcuts**. I would recommend to read the "details of defining keyboard shortcuts" first before creating any shortcuts.